# How do I stop my gltf character from walking through another gltf object in the scene? A-frame -> 8th Wall

Tags: physics-engine, navmesh, 8thwall-xr

I am using A-frame code in 8th Wall currently.
Both the character and scene are 3d models made in Blender 3.0.
My current attempt is to create a navigation mesh in blender and have been following this tutorial https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-inspector-plugin-recast and using this project template [https://www.8thwall.com/playground/joystick-movement.](https://www.8thwall.com/playground/joystick-movement)
For some reason, nothing I try is working. I have created a separate 3d plane and made it the navigation plane and made the character the nav-agent but it is still not working. Does anyone know a way I can get my 3d character to stop walking through the walls of my 3d scene?

If there are better ways of making sure my 3d character doesn't pass through other 3d objects in the scene I would greatly appreciate the help... been mulling over this for a week now...

Comment: Any luck? I've just started looking at the same thing and need to know how to make my meshes and/or geometry solid.

Comment: Not on the particular project, I was working on but I was directed here and it helped in a lot of other projects - check out the documentation on Simple Navigation Meshes. 
 https://github.com/AdaRoseCannon/aframe-xr-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

Wish I could contribute more, but I hope I can point you to the right direction. Check this library out: https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js

Its called cannon.js and its a physics engine for the browser.

Comment: the answer is outdated, the github repo is unmaintained for 8 years